# Как задать отступы внутри TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Как задать `padding` внутри текстового редактора TinyMCE.

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос так

```
.mce-edit-area  {
padding-left: 20px !important;
}
```

Правильно или нет, но работает...